# Position an image from the bottom

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that should be positioned near the bottom of the screen. I have a main image that is the background image and will resize with the browser size. I need the image over the background image to be 20-30px from the bottom no matter what size screen or if the screen is resized. (Image also must be centered.)

I am not sure how to go about doing this. What is the best way to do this?

Here is the code I have tried:

```css
.bottom{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: -355px; /* Image is 710 in width */
  left:50%;
  bottom:-20px;
 }
```

That code has the image centered on the page properly but not 20px from the bottom. Also I have content below the image and I want the content to stay below the image but it currently comes up over the image.

HTML:

```html
 <img class="bottom" src="src-path.png" alt="Text" />

 <p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>

 <!-- More Content here that consist of img and p tags. -->
```

Comment: Some code plz. Try http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: post your css and html code ......

Comment: It comes over do to you using absolute positioning,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I finally did this:

***CSS:***

```
.image_block    {
  /* Size of image is where the width/height come from */
   width: 710px;
   height: 500px;
}

.image_block a  {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}

.image_block img    {
   /*Nothing Specified */ 
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="image_block">
   <a href="#"><img src="src.png" alt="Alt Text" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess to position the image 20-30 px from the bottom you can use css property

`margin-bottom:30px;`  or 20px what ever value suits you.
for aligning at the center use `vertical-align:middle` Please do share the code that the thing is more clear. Hope I answered it correctly.

CSS Together must look like:-

```
margin-bottom:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Comment: Since the image which you want to position is already at the footer this adjustment must not be a problem.

Comment: @Lynda See this fiddle hope this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/LvfbP/ just adjust the margin left accordingly

Comment: @Lynda If you want the <p> to move along then include it inside the <div>

Answer (score 0):

You better use a CSS file, in which you declare a footer to be at the bottom of your page. Then put your image in your page, with class of that CSS and id of "footer". Clear enough?

Comment: I see that you've already tried what I suggested. For the text part, you should assign them to bottom as well. And do not use absolute if you want your image be at someplace fixed whether the page is maximized or normal.